# sslscan: TLS renegotiation: ERROR: Could not open a connection to host on port 443

Tags: tls1.2

I am trying to find out what ciphers a server is now currently accepting, so I used *sslscan* to check, but it stops after "TLS renegotiation":

> [root]# ./sslscan 10.116.41.12:443
>
> Version: 1.10.0-static
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.1m-dev xx XXX xxxx
>
> Testing SSL server 10.116.41.12 on port 443
>
> TLS renegotiation:
>
> ```
>  ERROR: Could not open a connection to host 10.116.41.12 on port 443.
> ```
>
> ERROR: Could not connect.

Port 443 is open on the server. What might be the problem of the server?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Adding the `--ipv4` flag solved it.

For example:

`sslscan --ipv4 localhost:1234`